# When shouldn't we use "the" to refer to "all the things" in general?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

[This site](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article) says:

> We also use the definite article:
>
> • to say something about all the things referred to by a noun:
>
> The wolf is not really a dangerous animal (= Wolves are not really
>   dangerous animals)
>
> The kangaroo is found only in Australia (= Kangaroos are found only in
>   Australia)
>
> The heart pumps blood around the body. (= Hearts pump blood around
>   bodies)

My question is that

In its basic sense, "**the**" refers to things that are specific.

For example, *I don't like **the** bird* (we are talking about that specific bird - the one that I know)

However, "The" is also used to refer to "all things in general".

For example, *The bird can sing*.

So, when I say "*I don't like **the** bird*", do I mean "*I don't like birds  in general*"?

"The" is very ambiguous, in this case.

So, When shouldn't we use "the" to refer to "all the things" in general?

Comment: Context makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article's purpose is to *orient* to the listener to your thought. Do you have any bird in mind, a particular bird, or Bird as class?

Since, as you say, **the** can refer to a particular bird or to the class, the article *alone* won't fully orient the listener.

If you have not mentioned a particular bird yet, but wish to refer to a particular bird, you can provide additional orienting information to make it clear to your listener that you have a particular bird in mind, not the class Bird:

> The bird *outside my window* ...
>
> The bird *that made its nest in our maple tree* ...
>
> The bird *is making* a cooing sound.

The class Bird cannot be outside your window. The class Bird cannot be the subject of actions-in-progress.

In conversations it is natural to include such orienting information without really thinking much about it.